# tableHTML in Shiny app - can't handle NULL

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to output a table via tableHTML that depends on some input in a Shiny app. In the example below, I want the table to depend on the radio button. I'm getting an error saying "Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level", so it seems it doesn't like my two return-statements. Any ideas how to go about this?

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Data on/off"),
                 choices = list("On", "Off"), 
                 selected = "Off"),
    tableHTML_output("mytable")
  )
)
  
server = function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- render_tableHTML({
    if ((input$radio == "On")) {
      return(tableHTML(mtcars))
    }
    else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above works when replacing `tableHTML_output` by `tableOutput` and `render_tableHTML` by `renderTable` and removing the `tableHMTL()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a package related issue.

Since we are dealing with plain html, we can use shiny::htmlOutput.

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    radioButtons("radio",
      label = h3("Data on/off"),
      choices = list("On", "Off"),
      selected = "On"
    ),
    htmlOutput("mytable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  html_table <- eventReactive(input$radio, {
    table <- if (input$radio == "On") {
      tableHTML(mtcars)
    }
    return(table)
  })

  output$mytable <- renderText(
    html_table()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another workaround is to have two render_tableHTML inside an observeEvent like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    radioButtons("radio",
      label = h3("Data on/off"),
      choices = list("On", "Off"),
      selected = "Off"
    ),
    tableHTML_output("mytable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$radio, {
    if (input$radio == "On") {
      output$mytable <- render_tableHTML({
        tableHTML(mtcars)
      })
    } else {
      output$mytable <- render_tableHTML({
        NULL
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```